# How to setup custom php.ini setting (mbstring.func_overload) by parameter in URL?

Tags: php

Good day!

I need to setup a custom value for `mbstring.func_overload` by parameter in URL.
Whole site working with `mbstring.func_overload = 2`.
But when there is a specific parameter in the URL i need to setup `mbstring.func_overload = 0`.

How to do this?

Thank you for all for helping!

Answer (score 0):

With a post request and a php file you can modify the contents of a file on the server. The problem is that you do not have access to the php.ini file

maybe you can try this php line:

```
ini_set('mbstring.func_overload', 0);
```

and in PHP to get the request URL you can use:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

### -----------------------------------------------

EDIT :

PHP_INI_USER The directive can be modified in a user script, with the
 ini_set () function, or via the Windows registry. Since PHP 5.3, the
entry can be defined in .user.ini.

PHP_INI_PERDIR The directive can be modified in the php.ini, .htaccess httpd.conf or .user.ini files (since PHP 5.3).

PHP_INI_SYSTEM The directive can be modified in the php.ini or httpd.conf files

PHP_INI_ALL The directive can be modified anywhere

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

and sadly `mbstring.func_overload` is in `PHP_INI_PERDIR` mod

Comment: PHP 7 installed and I can't modify mbstring.func_overload with ini_set().

Comment: sorry That's what I thought :/ the mbstring.func_overload      parameter can only be changed from the php.ini file.